# Слово "кандидат"

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика

Можно ли в предложении "Победу на выборах одержал X, но я продолжаю считать Y лучшим кандидатом на эту должность" использовать слово "кандидат"? Формально Y уже не является кандидатом на должность (выборы закончились), но можно ли употребить это слово в неформальном значении, примерно как в выражении "кандидат в мужья"?

Answer (score 1):

Фраза верна, если вы имеете в виду, что эти выборы - не последние, т.е. рассуждаете с прицелом на будущее. Если же вы просто хотите подвести итог прошедших выборов, я бы посоветовал написать "продолжаю считать, что Y был лучшим кандидатом на эту должность".

Comment: А почему **был**-то? Тут же мысль не та, кто был лучшим кандидатом, а именно то, что Игрек был бы лучшим работником/руководителем/исполнителем на данной должности. Тут не прошедшее время, тут максимум - сослагательное наклонение.

Comment: Igor хочет использовать именно слово "кандидат". С этим словом сослагательное наклонение тут неуместно. А настоящее время трудно оправдать, если Y уже не на что не претендует.

Comment: Y был лучшим среди кандидатов. Из этого не следует автоматически, что он был бы лучшим работником. Возможно, лучший работник свою кандидатуру и вовсе не выставлял.

Comment: *Из этого не следует автоматически, что он был бы лучшим работником.* А вот это вообще не по существу вопроса. Не надо за говорпящего додумывать. Если говорящий считает что Игрек был бы лучшим, то он имеет право сказать так, как он думает. Если хотите формально, то его "кандидат"  ***не означает*** "из числа тех,, кто выставлял свою кандидатуру. Лучший - и всё. Вряд ли говорящий столь глубоко вник в формальную логику, чтобы разбираться, о каком "типе" кандидатов идет речь.

Comment: @behemothus (1) Я тоже предполагал, что здесь "кандидат" - это всего лишь тот, кто теоретически может занять данную должность. Но все равно бессмысленно считать кого-то "кандидатом", если, например, новых выборов не будет никогда ("Моя девушка вышла замуж, но я продолжаю считать себя лучшим ее женихом." - на мой взгляд, нелепость, какой жених у замужней  женщины?) (2) Трудно сказать, что автор думает в сослагательном наклонении. Надо его спросить. Ясно лишь, что он спрашивает, можно ли использовать слово "кандидат".

Comment: Вы не будете против, если я ограничусь разбором вашего примера? Не обсуждаю, какой жених у замужней дамы, это вопрос понимания. Тут больше. Ваша аналогия неполная, чтобы не сказать плохая. ***Я считаю себя лучшим кандидатом на роль её мужа.*** - вот так бы я сказал. И вот тут сомнений у меня меньшею Если вообще есть.

Comment: @behemothus  "Я считаю себя лучшим кандидатом на роль её мужа." Тот, кто произносит эти слова, по меньшей мере готов на ней жениться, если существующий брак распадется. В противном случае он бы использовал прошедшее время или сослагательное наклонение. С этим Вы согласны?

Comment: Не уверен. Семантическая сослагательность не всегда выражается через грамматическую. Но предположим. В качестве некоего допущения примем, что так. Что из этого следует? Мне хочется понять, в чём тогда по-вашему отличие от исходной фразы. Мне кажется, упремся в понимание слова "кандидат" (хотел написать подробнее - посмотрел, всё это я уже говорил).

Comment: @behemothus Мне кажется, мы понимаем слово "кандидат"  одинаково (как синомим кандидатуры). Sibylla считает более верным использовать слово "кандидатура". В остальном разногласие только по поводу выражения сослагательности.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, вполне корректно.

Даже формально. Если признать, что Игрек уже не кандидат, он им всё равно был до момента выборов. Нигде не сказано, что говорящий имел в виду именно статус кандидата, а не факт участия.

Но дело даже не в этом. Слово "кандидат" не предполагает столь однозначной трактовки. Как в минимум в разговорной речи "кандидат" = "претендент". А тио и просто "кандидатура", т. е. личность, которую

Другое дело, что проще и понятнее можно было бы сказать, что ***"я считаю Игрек был бы лучшим руководителем (депутатом/президентом/директором - куда там выборы шли).*** Но это авторский стиль, не смею настаивать.

Наверное, можно примеры найти подобного употребления, но, полагаю, в данном случае это излишне.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что **есть разница между терминами кандидат и кандидатура** (они не очень чётко прописаны в словарях).

Пока идут выборы, мы имеем дело с кандидатами на должность президента, каждый из который выдвинут от своей партии для участия в данных конкретных выборах.

В результате выборов побеждает один кандидат, который становится президентом. С этого момента **остальные участники перестают быть кандидатами**.

Можно сказать: Победу на выборах одержал X, но я продолжаю считать Y лучшей (более подходящей) **кандидатурой** на должность  президента (**но не кандидатом на должность президента**).

**Примеры употребления слова "кандидатура":**

У меня есть подходящая кандидатура на примете. Наиболее подходящая кандидатура на этот пост  ― N.  Но у вас все-таки есть подходящая кандидатура на его место?

Comment: Sibylla, согласны ли Вы, что можно считать кого-то лучшей кандидатурой на должность президента только при условии, что когда-нибудь будут следующие выборы президента (и нельзя так говорить, оглядываясь назад, если уже принято, например, решение об упразднении этой должности)?

Comment: Мне кажется, что ситуацию не стоит связывать с конкретным временем (прошлым,  настоящим, будущим). Пока есть должность,  есть и люди, более или менее подходящие для этой должности.  И в любой момент можно сказать, что Y более подходящая кандидатура на должность президента, чем X.

Comment: Чтобы внести ясность, давайте возьмем крайний случай, когда должность не существует. "Победу на выборах президента СССР одержал Горбачев, но я продолжаю считать Y лучшей кандидатурой на эту должность." По-моему, так писать нельзя,  нужно ставить прошедшее время (Y был лучшим кандидатом/лучшей кандидатурой). @behemothus, как я понимаю, придерживается другого мнения. А Вы что думаете по этому поводу?

Comment: Думаю, что это уже буде сослагательное наклонение (речь идет о законченном эпизоде, условие ирреальное). "Победу на выборах президента СССР одержал Горбачев, но я продолжаю считать, что  Y был бы лучшей кандидатурой на эту должность."